# How to put %userprofile% in puppet exec

Tags: windows, puppet

I need to move a file form a temporary folder to a AppData folder, which is under the `%userprofile%` folder.

If I try this:

```
exec { 'copy' :
 command => 'C:\\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "copy C:\tmp\file.txt %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\"',
}
```

It throws an error. If I put the full path in, it works:

```
exec { 'copy' :
 command => 'C:\\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "copy C:\tmp\file.txt C:\\Users\usertest\AppData\Roaming\"',
}
```

But not all the computers have the same Username.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What error does it raise? What does `echo %userprofile%` in the `cmd` output?

Comment: You can probably do `... "copy C:\tmp\file.txt ' + ENV['USERPROFILE'] + '\AppData\Roaming\" ... '`

Comment: the command echo %userprofile% gives the correct path, the error is the exec returned 1 instead of 0

Comment: The `"copy C:\tmp\file.txt ' + ENV['USERPROFILE'] + '\AppData\Roaming\"` throws the next error: Resource type not found: ENV

Comment: Yes, we really need to see the error message here.

Comment: If u mean that u want the full error its the next:   `Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Resource type not found: ENV at /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/sapsilentinst/manifests/init.pp:68:78 on node pb03avbr.khlloreda.com`

Comment: I think that i might need to put this code in my puppet manifest but where? `Facter.add(:userprofile) do
     confine :kernel => %w{Windows}
     setcode do
         ENV['USERPROFILE']
     end
end`